# Unknown column '' in 'field list' because of datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, database, types

I'm trying to run this query on my server

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`userID`, `referenceName`) VALUES (`213526487623121521`, `@RandomUser#5524`)
```

on this table

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `userID` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referenceName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

but it always seem to spit out

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '295284816490790912' in 'field list'
```

Any ideas? Searching on Google seems to point that the datatypes are the culprit, but I'm not sure what datatypes should be used in these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape strings with single quotes `'` and column names with backticks:

```
 (`userID`, `referenceName`) VALUES ('213526487623121521', '@RandomUser#5524')
  ^ backtick                         ^ single quote
```

Comment: This worked. I thought that backticks are for everything in SQL. It seems that isnt the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 INSERT INTO `new_table` (`user_id`, `referenceName`) VALUES ('213526487623121521', '@RandomUser#5524')
```